# Columns Intersection

Tags: sql, plsql

Suppose i have a table like

```
ID     PROD     UNIT
1    |  100  | X
2   |  100   |  Y
3   |  100   |  Z
4   |  200   |  X
5   |  200   |  Y
6   |  300   |  Y
7   |  300   |  Z
```

I want to obtain an intersection of values from UNIT column for each code from PROD column, by an SQL query. The number of products in table is variable but i need to intersect UNIT for all products.
For my example, the result table would be a table with a single row, since all products from PROD have only one UNIT in common:

```
PROD    UNIT
300     Y
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? What did you find to not work?

Comment: @dfundako I tried some selects based on count(*)...but I come to realise using count/grouping by UNIT won't help at all in this problem...so at the moment I have no clue from where to start

Comment: You say your result set should only have Y as the UNIT because it is the only one which all PROD have in common. But why does your result set only have one PROD? What is the requirement for which value will appear?

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(PROD) as Prod, Unit
FROM
    TableName
GROUP BY
    Unit
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT PROD) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PROD) FROM TableName)
```

You need to Be able to compare the `DISTINCT Count of Products grouped by Unit` with the `DISTINCT Count of All Products in the table`.  You can use a sub query in the `HAVING` Clause to accomplish this.

I assumed you wanted the `Maximum PROD Id`, based on your outcome if you want something else of if you want all records simply use this as a derived table and join back to get your desired results.